# How to set table to center of the webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my table to centre of the webpage and I wam using align="right","centre" but non of them working,can some one point me in setting the table position!

```html
    <table style="table-layout:fixed;" align="right" cellspacing="2" border="0" cellpadding="0" id="Table_User" runat="server" >
         <tbody>
             table fields
         </tbody>   
    </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: why are you putting `align="right"` in the table element if you want to center it?

Comment: You've provided a live demo. Click the "Run code snippet". Look at the result. The code you've provided is littered with random `>` characters and has no table cells. Try providing a real [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

You can just use

```
<center>
<table....>


</table>
</center>
```

Comment: (HTML 5) Element 'centre' is not supported. I have tried earlier and I am getting this message

Comment: @RamSP Because it would be `center` and not `centre`. This is also outdated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: [The <center> tag is obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete)

Answer (score -1):

`It is true the center tag is deprecated
 Use this CSS and modify per your choice:

```
.center { margin: auto; width: 60%; padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: You are not wrong, but the `center` tag is deprecated. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @DasSaffe The `<center>` tag is [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete), not just deprecated.